# Wrong error message when suggesting an edit on a per-site-meta when not logged in

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, per-site-meta, unregistered-users

It is probably very unlikely for anybody to encounter this bug, but just for completeness’ sake:

If you try to access the edit link to a post on a per-site-meta, e.g., https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/915/edit  without being logged in (e.g., in a private browser window), you get the following error message:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.

This happens always – even if there is no suggested edit.